# Scaladoc inherit with notice

Tags: scala, javadoc, scaladoc

Is it possible to inherit scaladoc from parent type and add custom notice?

For example:

```
trait Parent {
  
  /** Add arbitrary number of key-value pairs to entity. */
  def addFields(fields: (String, String)*): this.type
}

class Child extends Parent {

   /** 
    * {@inheritdoc }
    *
    * @note Previously existing keys would be overwritten 
    */
  def addFields(fields: (String, String)*): this.type = ???
}
```

I am expecting to have the following scaladoc output:

```
class Child extends Parent {

   /** 
    * Add arbitrary number of key-value pairs to entity.
    *
    * @note Previously existing keys would be overwritten 
    */
  def addFields(fields: (String, String)*): this.type = ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have the solution in hand already. Unlike java, you just don't need to wrap `@inheritdoc` with curly braces. So the following will create the desired output:

```scala
trait Parent {
  
  /** Add arbitrary number of key-value pairs to entity. */
  def addFields(fields: (String, String)*): this.type
}

class Child extends Parent {

   /** 
    * @inheritdoc
    *
    * @note Previously existing keys would be overwritten 
    */
  override def addFields(fields: (String, String)*): this.type = ???
}
```

[I've attached a screenshot to show the final result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBPuc.png)

More can be read at [Generate API documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Scaladoc.html#Generate+API+documentation) by `sbt` and at [SCALADOC FOR LIBRARY AUTHORS](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/for-library-authors.html).